# Chunsize must be greater than 1 error pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using chinksize to split the files in pandas and it's working with chunksize = 1000000
hardcoded in the function.

But I need to pass as argument, using InfoWorks shell scripts. It is giving me the error:

```
chunksize must be greater than > =1
```

even though I am passing "1000000" in argument.

The second issue I have is when I pass output_file_path as a variable it is giving me the error:

shellscript:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/ifuser/TEST.py --env "SYST" --refresh "FALSE" --file_path "/SYST/KDP/REPORT.csv" --chunk_size 1000000
```

python script :

```
import pandas as pd
import textwrap
import time
import datetime
import os
import shutil
import boto3 #python -m pip install boto3
import base64
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import json
import logging
import csv
import argparse
import io
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import shutil
import glob





parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--env', type=str, required=True, help='DEV, SYST or PROD')
parser.add_argument('--refresh', type = str, required = False, help= 'if you want to refresh the load for the date', default='FALSE')
parser.add_argument('--file_path', type=str, required=True, help='file path of the report')
parser.add_argument('--chunk_size', type=str, required=True, help='file path of the report')



    with pd.read_csv(KA_File_Path, chunksize=**chunk_size**) as reader:
        for i,chunk in enumerate(reader):
            filename = "KADV_KLO_" + now +"_"+str(i+1)+".csv"
            chunk.to_csv(**output_file_path** + filename , index=False)
        #df.to_csv(f'filename , index=False)
```

hardcoded the output file path works, otherwise it doesn't

Comment: Please provide the whole traceback and working [mre].

Comment: You have **chunk_size** and **output_file_path** in your code, which doesn't feel like it can be valid python syntax. Did you try to make the text bold or is that actually your code?

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong, but what’s less clear is how this ought to be indented. Don’t make us guess; please [edit] to fix this. (On the desktop version of this site, paste your program, select it, and type ctrl-K to properly format it as code.) While you are editing, probably remove the parts which are unrelated to your actual question, and fix the repeated typos in a crucial term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your chunksize argument is a string. Please change it to `type=int`:

```
parser.add_argument('--chunk_size', type=int, required=True, help='file path of the report')
```

And btw, the help is incorrect too.